# obtener MAX en una tabla agrupada GROUP BY

Tags: sql

Hago la siguiente consulta y obtengo una tabla agrupada en la que me interesa quedarme solo con la fila que marca el máximo en la columna atletas_totales.
¿Como puedo obener solo la fila con el máximo?
Gracias a todos.

```
SELECT d.id_disciplina, d.nombre, COUNT (p.id_atleta) AS atletas_totales
FROM esquema1.tabla_disciplina d, esquema1.tabla_atletas a, esquema1.tabla_prueba p
WHERE a.id_atleta=p.id_atleta AND 
    d.id_disciplina=p.id_disciplina
GROUP BY d.id_disciplina, d.nombre
```

Comment: Si compartes todo la setencia sql sería de mucha utilidad. gracias.

Comment: Podrías aportar mas información del SELECT? De todas maneras si no te esta funcionando la función `MAX(valor)` una opción posible pero que no te recomiendo seria ordenar la tabla mediante ORDER BY y en el SELECT poner TOP 1. Esto lo que hará será devolverte la primera fila que en este caso si el ORDER BY lo has ordenado bien te devolverá la fila con el valor máximo que deseas.

Comment: Bienvenido Andres00 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Es muy importante que indiques mediante las etiquetas que "sabor" de sql estas usando: mysql, sql-server, oracle? etc.

Comment: Hola andres, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
select idDisciplina, Nombre, atletas_totales
from 
(
 SELECT d.id_disciplina as idDisciplina, d.nombre as Nombre, COUNT (p.id_atleta) AS atletas_totales
 FROM esquema1.tabla_disciplina d, esquema1.tabla_atletas a, esquema1.tabla_prueba p
 WHERE a.id_atleta=p.id_atleta AND 
 d.id_disciplina=p.id_disciplina
 GROUP BY d.id_disciplina, d.nombre
) x
where x.atletas_totales = (
                           SELECT TOP (1) COUNT (p.id_atleta) AS atletas_totales
                           FROM esquema1.tabla_disciplina d, esquema1.tabla_atletas a, esquema1.tabla_prueba p
                           WHERE a.id_atleta=p.id_atleta AND d.id_disciplina = p.id_disciplina     
                           GROUP BY d.id_disciplina, d.nombre
                           order by atletas_totales desc
                          ) y
```

Aquí se hacen varias **subconsultas**:

La primera **subconsulta** es la que ya tienes hecha, donde se hace el agrupamiento para obtener el total de atletas agrupados por **d.id_disciplina** y **d.nombre**, sobre esta **subconsulta** se hace un **select** mas general y en la **clausula where** de esta consulta general se haría una segunda **subconsulta** muy parecida a la primera, pero en esta nueva **subconsulta** se ordena descendentemente por el **campo atletas_totales**, de esta forma el máximo total de atletas seria el primer registro de todos los registros devueltos en esta segunda **subconsulta**, una vez que esta **subconsulta** queda ordenada descendentemente solamente se selecciona el primer registro y es este primer registro el que se usa para comparar con el **campo x.atletas_totales** de la **clausula where** de la consulta externa, devolviéndose finalmente el máximo deseado.